# Old User accounts deleted?

Tags: support, user-accounts, login

I registered on superuser.com and posted a couple of answers under the account:
https://superuser.com/users/8954/lazlow

However, today I visited the site again - having not logged in for a few months (maybe longer) and found that the page no longer existed. After logging in with my Google OpenID (same as used on StackOverflow/ServerFault) I was given the option to setup a new account as normal, which resulted in:
https://superuser.com/users/96197/lazlow

My question is - have very old/inactive accounts been deleted from the site? It's not too much of a problem, as I hadn't accumulated much in the way of reputation - but I'm intrigued to know why accounts need to be deleted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not really sure *why* (or if) accounts *need* to be deleted but there is a [StackOverflow Blog Post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/02/when-is-an-account-abandoned/) detailing what the criteria is for account to be removed.

Comment: That may be what has happened then - though I thought I had at least a handful of reputation on the site.

Comment: @Lazlow I did a search for all user accounts containing `lazlow` in them and for any accounts with the same email domain as yours. Your current account was the only result. I can't say for sure, but I"m guessing that TomBull is correct that your account may have been automatically deleted. It's possible that you _had_ some rep, but the questions you answered on were deleted or migrated to a different site, reducing you to 1 rep and allowing an auto-deletion.

Comment: Thanks @nhinkle for the confirmation.